# Writing a BeautifulSoup object to file Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a BeautifulSoup object to a file and am getting an error like some characters are unrecognized. Here is my code:

```
def save_soup(filename, s_obj):
    s_o = s_obj
    file = open('filename', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
    file.write(s_o.text)
    file.close()
```

While running it against a test file here is the error:

```
AssertionError: <!DOC[2506 chars]sult:<input class="txtfld2" id="bin3" on[567 chars]html> != <!DOC[2506 chars]sult:��� <input class="txtfld2" id="bin3" on[567 chars]html>
```

They are exactly the same except the ??? part. What am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is incomplete. There is your test? Where assert comes from? How do you load text back? Error might be in any of these parts. You should also mention that you are using python 3, cause python means python 2.

Comment: Please write a minimal code script that produce the error. Viz. http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this..just typecasting it to string will help!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(monterey.response.text, "html.parser")
f=open("res.txt","w")
f.write(str(soup))
f.close()
```